# Edit mode key map

Tags: spacemacs

Just learning spacemaces and wondering how to best interact with auto completion behavior...

So, below my cursor is the pipe `|`, if i type `def` for instance (elixir) then I get a nice

```
  def | do
  end
```

So I type my function name and a paren and now I have

```
  def my_fun(arg|) do
  end
```

I want now to stay in edit mode and press some key combo that says I am done with the parens so move me past the close paren, and then press it again since I am done with the def header so move me to the body.

Maybe this is a minor mode?  Not sure what the edit mode key mappings are generally.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand what is responsible for each behavior but I did learn that yasnippets is what I want for the behavior I described, and then M-/   expand a snippet where TAB moves me through the template cursor positions.